# Combine query in WP_User_Query()

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I am new user of WP_User_Query(). I don't know how to express whole situation. If I use below code I am getting good result.

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'last_name',
                'value' => $_POST['search'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),      
        )
    ));
```

If I use below code I am getting good result also.

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'organisation',
                'value' => 519,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),          
        )
    ));
```

I am trying to combine these two query like below.

```
$users = new WP_User_Query(array(
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'last_name',
                'value' => $_POST['search'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'organisation',
                'value' => 519,
                'compare' => 'LIKE',
            ),          
        )
    ));
```

But I am not getting expected output.

How can I combine these two queries ?

Comment: Have you tried changing ‘ OR’ to ‘AND’?

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. How to use ‘ OR’ to ‘AND’ ? I am new.

Comment: Literally in your code just change it.

Comment: Thanks @JacobPeattie. What is the meaning of `'compare' => 'LIKE',` ? Can I use here `'compare' => '=',` ? Thanks.

Comment: "I am not getting expected output" - then what output were you expecting? Users with a last name that matches the search query *and* that the users have a meta named `organisation` with the value `519`? "*Can I use here `'compare' => '=',` ?*" - yes you can (in fact, that's the default compare value), but whether it would return any results would depend on your meta value (e.g. if the value is a number, then `=` would return one or more results if there are users with `organisation` meta where the value is exactly `519`).

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ. Your comment is informative. Thanks.